Mean value theorem $F(h,k)-F(h,0)-[F(0,k)-F(0,0)]=[F_x(\overline{h},k)-F_x(\overline{h},0)]/h$
I'm reading a proof of Schwarz Theorem of mixed partial derivatives (https://www.ime.usp.br/~oliveira/ELE-SchwarzTheorem.pdf) and at some points the author writes

($F_x=\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}$). I understand that the MVT should gives two $h_1,h_2\in(0,h)$ such that
$$F(h,k)-F(h,0)-[F(0,k)-F(0,0)]=[F_x(h_1,k)-F_x(h_2,0)]/h$$
because the MVT tells us that $\exists h_1\in (0,h)$ such that
$$ \frac{F(h,k)-F(0,k)}{h-0}=F_x(h_1,k)$$
and $\exists h_2\in (0,h)$ such that
$$ \frac{F(h,0)-F(0,0)}{h-0}=F_x(h_2,0)$$
But I don't get why the author writes a single $\overline{h}\in (0,h)$ for both of them. Thanks in advance, any comment is appreaciated.

The author applies the mean value theorem to the function
$$
x\mapsto F(x,k)-F(x,0)=:G(x)
$$
whose derivative is
$$
G'(x)=F_x(x,k)-F_x(x,0).
$$
Therefore
$$
[F(h,k)-F(h,0)]-[F(0,k)-F(0,0)]=G(h)-G(0)=G'(\bar h)h=[F_x(\bar h,k)-F_x(\bar h,0)]h
$$
for some $\bar h$ between $0$ and $h$.

Amazing, thank you very much
